# Unique value in multiple nodes

Tags: ros, simulation, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm running multiple nodes (started by one launch-file) and a few of them are logging data at the same time independently. In the end I'd like to evaluate these different log-files in another program (lets say MATLAB). The issue is the following: If I'm creating 3 different logfiles in 3 different nodes I don't want to enter 3 different filenames in MATLAB later. So here the question: Can I somehow find a value that is unique for every simulation (every start of the launch-file) and that every node has access to?
I was thinking about constant values like the start time of the core and then put this value into each logfile-name, e.g.

log1-10-18-09-30-30.txt          # created by node 1

log2-10-18-09-30-30.txt          # created by node 2

log3-10-18-09-30-30.txt          # created by node 3

with October 18th, 09:30:30 the start time of the core.
It doesn't necessarily need to be the start time though, it just needs to be the same value for every node.
(Nodes are written in Python and Julia).

Thank you for any advice or ideas!

Best,
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245959/unique-value-in-multiple-nodes/) by [maxb](https://answers.ros.org/users/28283/maxb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS loads a parameter `/run_id` on the parameter server which is unique for every start of the `roscore`. You could read this from the parameter server in your nodes and add that. It is not a time, and looks something like this `8e6217fa-95c5-11e6-a04a-<MAC>`, but will probably suit your needs, if you are not requireing the actual time.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maxb](https://answers.ros.org/users/28283/maxb/) on 2016-10-19**:
Cool thank you, just what I was looking for!!